# How to stop JQuery UI Autocomplete from clearing previouse entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am just learning to use JQuery UI's autocomplete feature and I am using it to add tags to a tag_list property of a model. However when I select a tag from the list of options it removes any previouse values in the input field.

How do I append the selected tag to the comma seperated tag list in the input feild rather than overwriting it?

Thanks

```
#  Autocomlete Peice Tags
    $( "#search_tag_list" ).autocomplete({
      source: $( "#search_tag_list" ).data('autocomplete-source') #get url from html data attribute
    });
```

CoffeeScript:

```
#  Autocomlete Search Tagss
    split = ( val ) ->
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );


    extractLast = ( term ) ->
      return split( term ).pop();


    extractWithoutLast = ( term ) ->
      term = split( term );
      term.pop();
      return term;


    $( "#search_tag_list" )
#   don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", ( event ) ->
      if ( event.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active )
        event.preventDefault();
      )
    .autocomplete({
      source: ( request, response ) ->
        $.getJSON( $( "#search_tag_list" ).data('autocomplete-source'),
          {
            term: extractLast( request.term ),
#           exclude already selected values:
            exclude: extractWithoutLast( request.term )
          },
          response
        );
      ,
      search: ->
#       custom minLength
        term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 )
          return false;
      ,
      focus: ->
#       prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      ,
      select: ( event, ui ) ->
        terms = split( this.value );
#       remove the current input
        terms.pop();
#       add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
#       add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Any chance to see the script you have a problem with? :-)

Comment: sure, I added in the javascript. At the moment it is getting an array of tags from the url in the 'autocomplete-source' data tag on the '#search_tag_list' field

Comment: In [jQueryUI DOCS](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) is a nice demo (with source code) of the *autocomplete* widget set up for multiple input tags, with remote source. The code you have in your question provide just basic/default functionality which is suitable only for single value in input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using just default functionality of the autocomplete plugin.

Following the [Autocomplete widget Docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) you have to set the widget to show multiple tags/values in your autocomplete field:

(tweaked up a bit to prevent already choosed tags being presented in search results again)

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");

    $term = trim($_GET['term']);
    // filter the array:
    $array = preg_grep("/$term/", $array);
    // check if there's anything to exclude:
    if(isset($_GET['exclude'])){
         // remove already selected values:
         $array = array_diff( $array, $_GET['exclude'] );
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

**Script:** ([Autocomplete widget Docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple))

```
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    function extractWithoutLast( term ) {
        var term = split( term );
        term.pop();
        return term;
    }

    $( "#search_tag_list" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.getJSON( $( "#search_tag_list" ).data('autocomplete-source'), {
                term: extractLast( request.term ),
                // exclude already selected values:
                exclude: extractWithoutLast( request.term )
            }, response );
    },
    search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the reply this is great. I'm working in rails so have tried to convert this over to coffeescript. However I connot quite get it to work. I'm getting the autocomplete functionality but its not giving any autocomplete functionality once one tag has been selected. Ive added my coffeescript in the original question. Thanks again!

Comment: @ Cu1ture, Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with coffeescript. This answer is for the original question which was about javascript, jquery and autocomplete.

Comment: Ok no problem I just cant work out where the error is. Thanks for the help!